# easiest way to create free standing Mac OS X perl applications

Tags: macos, perl, osx-lion

This may be a basic question. I have written a small perl script to run on a Mac running OS X which can be called from the finder by double clicking in the normal way. The file is executable and contains starts with `#!/usr/bin/perl` and input and output is via the clipboard. This all works but automatically opens a terminal window which the user must then close once execution is finished.

Is there an easy way to run this program as an application without opening a terminal? Can one do this with the native OS X perl? Or do I need to download something? Since the program will also be used by other users, the simpler the solution to better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the application "**AppleScript Editor**" : open it

Copy/paste this script

```
tell me to path to resource "this Name.pl" in directory "Scripts"
do shell script (quoted form of POSIX path of the result)
```

In the first line, change the name "**this Name.pl**" by the name of your perl file.

Save as --> Application

In the Finder :
Copy your perl file (executable) to the folder "*/Contents/Resources/Scripts*" of the created application

Comment: Getting 'error "A resource wasn’t found." number -192'. Are there additional parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For Win32/Linux/or Mac use http://www.cavapackager.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're distributing your application to others, Platypus includes an installer to build free-standing apps around scripts.

[Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) supports Perl, Python, PHP, Ruby, Swift, Expect, Tcl, AppleScript or any other user-specified interpreter. It is free, open-source software distributed under the terms of the three-clause BSD license.  It can run silently (without opening a terminal window, as you require), or can display graphical feedback of script execution as progress bar, text window with script output, droplet, WebKit HTML rendering or status item menu.